# Account hierarchy in salesforce

Tags: hierarchy, data-model

We have school district offices that have numerous buildings such as high schools, middle schools, and elementary schools underneath them.  We need a way to assign the district office as the Parent Account and the buildings as the children accounts and link them together

Any help on how this can be accomplished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce has standard functionality for this - the account hierarchy.  That allows you to specify a parent account via a lookup type field on the child account.

A good place to start is the Salesforce help:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=account_parent.htm&language=en_US